# USB 1 to 2 switch wiring

Tags: usb, wiring, switching, toggle-switch

I have 1 USB hub with mouse and keyboard connected and I'd like to build a switch to be able to switch this hub between 2 PCs. I have a 3-position toggle switch with only 2 contact pairs, so I can switch only 2 wires at a time.

Ok I can connect all GND contacts of all three USBs together, but what about +5 VCC contacts? Can I safely connect all of them together just like GND or should I buy a switch for 3 pairs? Maybe is it possible to connect VCC contacts using diodes or some guard circuit?

Are other combinations for switching possible? (VCC + D-, VCC + D+)

[image]

Switch

[image]

Comment: Not safe. The 5V supplies are shorted together so PC that is powered up or has higher voltage will try to feed power also to the PC that is unpowered or has lower voltage. Connecting supplies together with a diode will also violate USB specs. If you don't want to fry your PCs or their USB ports, the instead of byuing a new 3 pole switch, buy a ready made product to safely switch USB devices between different PCs.

Comment: @Justme do you think a 3-pole switch is also not safe, if I switch 5V, D+ and D-? It seems in this case just the same if I pull out USB cable from one PC and connect it to the second PC

Comment: It is better but it still won't match unplugging and replugging of a cable. USB requires that data pins disconnect first and power pins last when unplugging, and that power pins connect first and data pins last when replugging. I would not personally want to use a 3-pole switch with PCs and USB devices I own, I would not trust such a DIY solution, when products exist to do it properly at around 20 dollars or euros.

Comment: @Justme I did not know it, just looked and 2 middle pins in usb connector are really shorter, appreciate your help, maybe you could make an answer from your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making DIY keyboard/mouse USB switch between two PCs is not worth the risk of damaging the PCs, as products designed for this exist and don't cost much more that parts if you try to make your own.

At least a 3-pole switch would be required so that the devices are powered from same PC where the data connections go to. But a three pole switch will not guarantee a safe USB disconnection and connection sequence, because data pins are first to disconnect and last to reconnect.